Locust Worker Setup Failing
locust -f locust_test.py --master-host=10.5.0.3 --master --master-port=8089 > master.log 2>&1 & for x in {1..7};  do locust -f locust_test.py --master-host=10.5.0.3 --master-port=8089 --worker > worker_$x.log 2>&1 & done
[2024-08-08 09:58:47,279] locust-32-core-qwed/WARNING/locust.runners: Failed to connect to master 10.5.0.3:8089, retry 18/60.

This is almost certainly a mistake: --master-port=8089
8089 is the web UI port of the master, so you shouldn't try to run the master-worker ZeroMQ communication on that port as well. Use some other port, or remove the parameter entirely to leave it at the default (5557).
If I have time I'll investigate if locust can just throw an error and refuse to start if the port is busy.
Also, btw, nowadays you don't have to script launching master/workers. Just specify --processes 7 to launch a master and 7 workers all at once, see https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html#single-machine
